# How to reload fixtures in a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, minitest, fixtures

I'm trying to test an RSS feed by comparing a dynamically generated feed against a known output. To make this work, I need to load fixtures with the time frozen. The following works, but it seems overkill to reset the database by reloading the schema and the fixtures.

```
# test/integration/feed_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
load 'Rakefile'

class FeedTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    # Normalize time in order to match fixture file
    travel_to Time.zone.parse('2015-03-01T12:00:00') do
      silence_stream(STDOUT) do
        # anything written to STDOUT here will be silenced
        Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].reenable
        Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
      end
      Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].reenable
      Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].invoke
    end
  end

  test 'feed matches fixture file' do
    get feed_path
    assert_equal contents('feed.atom'), response.body
  end
end

# test/test_helper.rb
module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    fixtures :all

    def contents(file_name)
      IO.read "test/fixtures/files/#{file_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

I can't figure out how to reload just the projects filter inside a `travel_to` block. I also can't get `travel_to` to work in `test_helper.rb`.

But, the real problem with this approach is that reloading the `Rakefile` causes the following spurious warnings from the secure_headers gem:

```
$ rake test
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:1: warning: already initialized constant INLINE_SCRIPT_REGEX
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:1: warning: previous definition of INLINE_SCRIPT_REGEX was here
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:2: warning: already initialized constant INLINE_STYLE_REGEX
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:2: warning: previous definition of INLINE_STYLE_REGEX was here
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:3: warning: already initialized constant INLINE_HASH_SCRIPT_HELPER_REGEX
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:3: warning: previous definition of INLINE_HASH_SCRIPT_HELPER_REGEX was here
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:4: warning: already initialized constant INLINE_HASH_STYLE_HELPER_REGEX
/Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/secure_headers-3.3.1/lib/tasks/tasks.rake:4: warning: previous definition of INLINE_HASH_STYLE_HELPER_REGEX was here
Run options: --seed 17868

# Running:

........................................................................................................

Finished in 17.397614s, 5.9778 runs/s, 191.3481 assertions/s.

104 runs, 3329 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Coverage report generated for MiniTest to /Users/dan/Dropbox/Documents/dev/cii-best-practices-badge/coverage. 754 / 781 LOC (96.54%) covered.
```

It seems like I should be able to reload some of the fixtures without using rake at all, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: Have you tried this with a different version of Ruby, perhaps 2.3.1 or 2.2.5?  Ruby 2.3.0 has been reported as "buggy".

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. I install Ruby 2.3.1 and get identical messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix that resolved my issue:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'test_helper'
load 'Rakefile'

class FeedTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Turn off transactional fixtures for this test since we are loading
  # the fixtures database anyway. This will prevent the timestamp change
  # from spilling into other tests.
  self.use_transactional_tests = false

  setup do
    # Ensure the test db has its environment metadata set to test,
    # otherwise tasks farther down will fail.  New for Rails 5
    Rake::Task['db:environment:set'].invoke
    # Normalize time in order to match fixture file
    travel_to Time.zone.parse('2015-03-01T12:00:00') do
      ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
      Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].reenable
      Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].reenable
      Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].invoke
    end
  end

  test 'feed matches fixture file' do
    get feed_path
    assert_equal contents('feed.atom'), response.body
  end
end
```